# Почему не возвращаются данные из БД?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

API Контроллер

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        using (LeaderBordContext db = new LeaderBordContext())
            {
                List<Game> games = db.Games.OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
                HttpResponseMessage response;
                response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, games);
                return response;
            }
    }
```

Контекст

```
    public class LeaderBordContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Gamer> Gamers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }

        public LeaderBordContext()
            : base("LeaderBordContext")
        {}
    }
```

Сервер возвращает ошибку

> "An error has occurred.",   "ExceptionMessage": "Cannot create file
>   'C:\Users\ПК\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\LeaderBord\LeaderBord\App_Data\lbdb.mdf' because it
>   already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the
>   operation. CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not
>   be created. Check related errors.",   "ExceptionType":
>   "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException"

Строку подключения к БД в файле Web.config указал. Что может быть?

Comment: Покажите Web.config, а точнее connectionStrings.

Comment: Вот <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LeaderBordContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\lbdb.mdf';Integrated Security=True"
 providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

Comment: Возможно нужно отключить инициализацию по умолчании. Добавьте в конструктор.  System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<LeaderBordContext >(null);

Comment: У меня инициализатор включен. Я инициализирую базу вот таким инициализатором DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(пробовал и другие). Вызываю функцию Seed. Все нормально работает и коннектится к базе если через подход MVC. А вот через API вот такая беда. Ваш код не подошел. Неверный синтаксис

Comment: Пройдите по адресу "C:\Users\ПК\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\LeaderBord\LeaderBord\App_Data\" и удалите файл lbdb.mdf и попробуйте запустить проект заново.